variadic template failed to compile, compiler bug?
I reduced my code to this very short example:
template<class ...F>
struct A
{
    A(std::convertible_to<std::tuple<std::string, F>> auto&&... actions);
    std::tuple<std::tuple<std::string, F>...> _actions;
};

template<class ...F>
A<F...>::A(std::convertible_to<std::tuple<std::string, F>> auto&&... actions)
    : _actions{ std::tuple{ actions... } }{}

I don't see anything wrong with it. But clang (-std=c++23) gives this error:
<source>:13:66: error: pack expansion contains parameter packs 'actions:auto' and 'F' that have different lengths (1 vs. 0)
   13 | A<F...>::A(std::convertible_to<std::tuple<std::string, F>> auto&&... actions)
      |                                                        ~         ^   ~~~~~~~
<source>:13:10: note: while calculating associated constraint of template '' here
   13 | A<F...>::A(std::convertible_to<std::tuple<std::string, F>> auto&&... actions)
      |          ^
<source>:13:10: error: out-of-line definition of 'A<F...>' does not match any declaration in 'A<F...>'
   13 | A<F...>::A(std::convertible_to<std::tuple<std::string, F>> auto&&... actions)
      |          ^
2 errors generated.

Compiler Explorer Demo

Always post driver code(specially with templates otherwise they won't be instnatiated) that shows how you're supposed to use them. This will also make question more clear as people can then suggest other alternatives.

All compilers accept your program

When using compiler explorer to show a program always use trunk. You can also add the next latest version there. Without any instantiation the program may be IFNDR

@PepijnKramer What do you mean? It's allowed to define the constructor out of line.

Summarizing user12002570's comments, this is a Clang 18 bug that was already fixed in trunk.

@HolyBlackCat It is... :) But nvm... I  made mistakes too

@user12002570 -- I cannot use trunk, I see the bug in v. 17 and 18

@Gene Yes, I see that in this demo. version 18 rejects the code but trunk accepts it. So they've fixed it.

This seems to be a clang bug that was fixed in latest clang trunk. Demo
